# ca_driver deploy catkin_make

Tags: ros, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I try to deploy ca_driver from create_autonomy to multiple devices.

Problem: catkin_make install did not install ca_driver to install-dir.

Bug or feature ?
Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249832/ca_driver-deploy-catkin_make/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2016-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Problem: catkin_make install did not install ca_driver to install-dir.

This is actually not a problem with `catkin_make`: the current `CMakeLists.txt` of `ca_driver` ([here](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/blob/6a538fbaa492e3054fb9a1eabff8e24979751d01/ca_driver/CMakeLists.txt)) simply does not contain any `install(..)` statements.

Running `catkin_make install` will therefore not install anything, as there are no instructions to do so.

I'd report this to the `AutonomyLab` people over at their [issue tracker](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2016-12-11**:
I've copied the binary manually to destination.

Thanks for the fast answer
Cheers
Chrimo

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-12**:
It would be really nice if you could report this to their issue tracker, as that would make this work for other users as well.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-12-12**:
Expect an update to create_autonomy tonight with install rules (with some other small changes I've been meaning to get to as well).